# TeXstudio - MiKTeX compile error

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, texstudio

I have an issue with MiKTeX and TeXstudio which won't compile anything.

I am using overleaf but since my project got bigger and compiles very slow and often not at all
I tried to switch to my computer.

I followed all the instructions I found. MiKTeX is installed at first for single user as recommended and then for all users just in case TeXstudio had issues with this setting.
I am describing briefly all the steps I took and give you the log files from both. I wanted to use a scroll box but I didn't know how to set it up so I am sorry for the long post. Thank you in advance and here they are

I tried default settings, deleting the .ini file, all the folder, selecting the path for each command. Whatever is there I did try it.

MiKTeX was uninstalled and reinstalled for single user (path set to user AppData) and for all users (path set to Program Files).
The correct path was set to Commands ($PATH)

Tried to compile a simple Hello World from a saved file named untitled or from a new unsaved file.

TeXstudio unistalled and reinstalled with all folders cleaned up no remains.

The TexStudio error message Builb and view and default for all default compilers

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Athan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

The TeXstudio log with default settings and xelatex which I want to use

dpi: 96
where pdflatex: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe

```
PDFLATEX: pdflatex.exe -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 20.12)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.3; using 4.3compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.1; using 4.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

TeXstudio:

```
Path        : C:\Program Files\texstudio\texstudio.exe
Program call: C:\Program Files\texstudio\texstudio.exe
Setting file: C:\Users\Athan\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\texstudio.ini
```

Command configuration in TeXstudio:

```
Internal Precompile (internal-pre-compile): txs:///pre-compile | txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography
Ps2Pdf (ps2pdf): ps2pdf.exe %.ps
External PDF Viewer (view-pdf-external): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "?am.pdf"
BibTeX 8-Bit (bibtex8): bibtex8.exe %
Default Index Tool (index): txs:///makeindex
PS Viewer (view-ps): "C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsview64.exe" "?am.ps"
Ghostscript (gs): mgs.exe "?am.ps"
PDF Viewer (view-pdf): txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded
Default Glossary Tool (glossary): txs:///makeglossaries
Texindy (texindy): texindy.exe %.idx
PdfLaTeX (pdflatex) (r): pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
GIT (git): git.exe 
Makeglossaries (makeglossaries): makeglossaries.exe %
DVI->PS->PDF Chain (dvi-ps-pdf-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view-pdf
SVN (svn): 
Default Bibliography Tool (bibliography): txs:///bibtex
BibTeX (bibtex): bibtex.exe %
Build & View (quick): txs:///compile | txs:///view
texdoc (texdoc): texdoc.exe 
LuaLaTeX (lualatex) (r): lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
DVI Viewer (view-dvi): "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\yap.exe" -1 -s @?"c:ame "?am.dvi"
DviPs (dvips): dvips.exe -o %.ps %.dvi
Asymptote DVI Chain (asy-dvi-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///asy | txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
DviPng (dvipng): dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 %.dvi
Default Compiler (compile) (r): txs:///xelatex
External Terminal (terminal-external): C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DVI->PDF Chain (dvi-pdf-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvipdf | txs:///view-pdf
DVI Chain (dvi-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
Latexmk (latexmk): latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %
SVNADMIN (svnadmin): 
Makeindex (makeindex): makeindex.exe %.idx
XeLaTeX (xelatex) (r): xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
Asymptote PDF Chain (asy-pdf-chain): txs:///pdflatex | txs:///asy | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Recompile Bibliography (recompile-bibliography): txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile
MetaPost (metapost): mpost.exe -interaction=nonstopmode ?me)
Precompile (pre-compile): 
Default Viewer (view): txs:///view-pdf
Biber (biber): biber.exe %
DviPdf (dvipdf): dvipdfmx.exe %.dvi
PDF Chain (pdf-chain): txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Asymptote (asy): asy.exe ?m*.asy
LaTeX (latex) (r): latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
PS Chain (ps-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///view-ps
```

Additional Search Paths:

```
Command: 
Log: 
Pdf:
```

And the MiKTeX log

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\Athan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

```
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:715
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 FATAL xelatex - Line: 715
2021-01-16 00:18:55,984+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (3616) finishes with exit code 1
2021-01-16 00:25:34,298+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (11536) started by 'texstudio' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "System Report.tex"
2021-01-16 00:25:34,313+0200 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-01-16 00:25:34,391+0200 INFO  xelatex - going to create file: xelatex.fmt
2021-01-16 00:25:34,470+0200 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=xelatex --engine=xetex
2021-01-16 00:25:36,957+0200 ERROR xelatex - C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-01-16 00:25:36,957+0200 ERROR xelatex - output:
2021-01-16 00:25:36,957+0200 ERROR xelatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
```

This is the requested log file

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.12) (INITEX)  16 JAN 2021 00:25
entering extended mode
**"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg")
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
\l_tmpb_int=\count26
\g_tmpa_int=\count27
\g_tmpb_int=\count28
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
\c_log_iow=\count33
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count35
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
\l__iow_indent_int=\count37
\c_zero_dim=\dimen14
\c_max_dim=\dimen15
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19
\c_zero_skip=\skip14
\c_max_skip=\skip15
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip16
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip17
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip19
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count38
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20
\g__intarray_font_int=\count40
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
\g__fp_array_int=\count50
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count51
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count52
\l__sort_length_int=\count53
\l__sort_min_int=\count54
\l__sort_top_int=\count55
\l__sort_max_int=\count56
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count57
\l__sort_block_int=\count58
\l__sort_begin_int=\count59
\l__sort_end_int=\count60
\l__sort_A_int=\count61
\l__sort_B_int=\count62
\l__sort_C_int=\count63
\l__str_modulo_int=\count64
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count65
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count66
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count67
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count68
\l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count69
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count70
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count71
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count72
\l__regex_balance_int=\count73
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count74
\l__regex_mode_int=\count75
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count76
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count77
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count78
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count79
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count80
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count81
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count82
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count83
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count84
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count85
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count86
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count87
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count88
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count89
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count90
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count91
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count92
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count93
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count94
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count95
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count96
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count97
\l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count98
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count99
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count100
\l__regex_step_int=\count101
\l__regex_min_thread_int=\count102
\l__regex_max_thread_int=\count103
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count104
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count105
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count106
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count107
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count108
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count109
\c_empty_box=\box12
\l_tmpa_box=\box13
\l_tmpb_box=\box14
\g_tmpa_box=\box15
\g_tmpb_box=\box16
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen24
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28
\l__box_internal_box=\box17
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box18
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
\c_empty_coffin=\box19
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box23
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box24
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.28684   }
       
    No pages of output.
```

This is the latest entry to my question. All packages are installed for both admin and user and doublechecked for updates.

The error message is the same and I'll post the logs. FYI if there is any .pdf file with the name as the .tex file in the folder it'll open at preview.
New .pdf cannot be created. Here are the log files

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.12) (INITEX)  16 JAN 2021 18:41
entering extended mode
**"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg")
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
\l_tmpb_int=\count26
\g_tmpa_int=\count27
\g_tmpb_int=\count28
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
\c_log_iow=\count33
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count35
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
\l__iow_indent_int=\count37
\c_zero_dim=\dimen14
\c_max_dim=\dimen15
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19
\c_zero_skip=\skip14
\c_max_skip=\skip15
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip16
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip17
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip19
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count38
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20
\g__intarray_font_int=\count40
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
\g__fp_array_int=\count50
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count51
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count52
\l__sort_length_int=\count53
\l__sort_min_int=\count54
\l__sort_top_int=\count55
\l__sort_max_int=\count56
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count57
\l__sort_block_int=\count58
\l__sort_begin_int=\count59
\l__sort_end_int=\count60
\l__sort_A_int=\count61
\l__sort_B_int=\count62
\l__sort_C_int=\count63
\l__str_modulo_int=\count64
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count65
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count66
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count67
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count68
\l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count69
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count70
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count71
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count72
\l__regex_balance_int=\count73
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count74
\l__regex_mode_int=\count75
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count76
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count77
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count78
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count79
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count80
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count81
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count82
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count83
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count84
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count85
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count86
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count87
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count88
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count89
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count90
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count91
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count92
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count93
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count94
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count95
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count96
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count97
\l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count98
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count99
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count100
\l__regex_step_int=\count101
\l__regex_min_thread_int=\count102
\l__regex_max_thread_int=\count103
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count104
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count105
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count106
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count107
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count108
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count109
\c_empty_box=\box12
\l_tmpa_box=\box13
\l_tmpb_box=\box14
\g_tmpa_box=\box15
\g_tmpb_box=\box16
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen24
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28
\l__box_internal_box=\box17
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box18
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
\c_empty_coffin=\box19
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box23
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box24
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28684   }
           
No pages of output.
```

that's the new makefmt xelatex log
and the next is the one pointed at the error message by TeXstudio

```
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Athan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:715
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 FATAL xelatex - Line: 715
2021-01-16 18:41:54,027+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (12316) finishes with exit code 1
2021-01-16 18:42:19,107+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (960) started by 'texstudio' with command line: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode document.tex
2021-01-16 18:42:19,122+0200 INFO  xelatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-01-16 18:42:19,169+0200 INFO  xelatex - going to create file: xelatex.fmt
2021-01-16 18:42:19,341+0200 INFO  xelatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=xelatex --engine=xetex
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 ERROR xelatex - C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 ERROR xelatex - output:
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 ERROR xelatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Athan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:715
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex - Info: fileName="xelatex.fmt"
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 FATAL xelatex - Line: 715
2021-01-16 18:42:24,920+0200 INFO  xelatex - this process (960) finishes with exit code 1
```

I have no idea why this is happening. It is very straightforward.

No errors during installation and this happens with TeXworks installed along MiKTeX as well

Comment: something did go wrong when creating the format: "The memory dump file could not be found.".  There should be log-file from the format creation in `... \AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\xelatex`. Find it and show the content.

Comment: can you find UnicodeData.txt in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\generic\unicode\unicode-data`? Is the folder `unicode-data` there?